# Creating a Rectangle object and attaching an Image to it in Java

Tags: java, image, graphics, shapes

so I have this homework assignment where I have to create an rectangular object that can move around in a GUI and it must have a certain image specific to it (depending on the class) pasted on to the object. We haven't learned any graphics stuff stuff so i'm not sure what mehtods or anything to use. One the shapes are created I assume to move them I just change the x and y positions and draw them again or something like that. Someone suggested using imageicon or something. But could anybody give me some more specific advice?

Comment: [2D Graphics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/),  [Reading/Loading an Image](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/loadimage.html), [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html), [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/)

Comment: `Someone suggested using imageicon` - See [How to Use Icons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html). Take a look at the Table of Contents as the tutorial contains most of the Swing basics.

Comment: Take a look at some of @MadProgrammer's answers for [similar questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A992484+%5Bjava%5D+%5Bswing%5D+animation), then some of [mine](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A522444+%5Bjava%5D+%5Bswing%5D+animation), and then of course [camickr's](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A131872+%5Bjava%5D+%5Bswing%5D+animation).